# Push into Azure DevOps GIT Repo

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to Push a new file into an Azure Devops Git Repo using PowerShell, I am getting an error:

"Fatal: Cannot prompt because terminal prompts have been disabled"

I am using an YAML pipeline to run the PowerShell script in the build server(where the agents are hosted) and need to push the file from the build server to the Git repo.

I tried passing the token/credentials: http://(token)abcdev/_git.. but getting the same error.

Is there a way I could push files into the Repo every time the pipeline runs?